# Immutable.js - fromJS generate Record in place of Map

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I've been having a play with React, Redux and Immutable and have come across something I really dislike. I have a large JSON data set returned from the server which I'm parsing into Immutable using the fromJS helper.

All well and good, however when it comes to accessing the properties in my Components I'm forced to use the Immutable specific getters and setters. My issue is being bound to Immutable, say along the line I decided to change this I would have to go through each and every Component and adjust accordingly.

Which brings me to my question, currently fromJS returns Lists and Maps, is it possible to replace the Maps with Records?

This would then decouple my Components from Immutable and have native properties, e.g `user.name` rather than `user.get('name')`.

I've read a little about revivers but can't seem to find a similar use case.

I've had a play with the following but I'm unsure if it's the best solution:

```
var result = Immutable.fromJS({

    id: 2039428947,
    name: 'James',
    email: 'james@email.com',
    country: 'United Kingdom'

}, function(key, value) {

    var obj = Immutable.Record(value.toJS());

    return new obj(value);

});
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't _have_ to use Immutable. There are [alternatives](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) that may suit you better, or you can create new native objects from your state in the reducer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I've wrapped this up in a tiny package that can do this for you:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable-parsejs

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

For anyone else who's interested in using ImmutableJS but also having the ability to use native properties in Components, e.g `user.name` instead of `user.get('name')`, simply use the below function instead of `fromJS`:

```
function convertJs(js) {

   if(typeof js !== 'object' || js === null) {

       return js;

   }

   if(Array.isArray(js)) {

       return Seq(js).map(convertJs).toList();

   }

   let obj = Record(js);

   obj = new obj(Seq(js).map(convertJs));

   return obj;

}
```

One thing to keep in mind is property conflicts, make sure that the objects you feed into the function don't contain property names used by ImmutableJs, ***size*** is a good example. If there is a conflict you'll get the following message with no indication of where the problem is:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot set on an immutable record

Comment: I am not understanding when and why a user would use "Record". you know any resources explaining this in detail?

Comment: As per the docs: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Record
**Record** acts as a regular js object, allowing you to access properties in the same way, e.g user.name as opposed to a **Map** which uses the .get method, e.g user.get('name'); They also allow you to enforce a set number of properties and can act as built in documentation as their contents are clearly shown. Maps in contrast can have any number of properties which are not strictly enforced.

Comment: That comment of property names was very good, helped me out! for me the property error was already used, so i had to rename it

Comment: I hadn't considered property conflicts, +1 for solving my broken nested Records.

Comment: thanks if i recommend you to ship it as an npm module

Comment: @FareedAlnamrouti By popular demand:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable-parsejs